# jquery append in relation to stylesheet and class function

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, class

Fairly new, working from a scratch PHP/mySQL login page and adding features as i learn them..

Most recent addition is an ajax credential validation, that upon success replaces the .html() of the form with a success message, followed by an .append() to the navbar that adds a logout button, all with no page refresh.

The above process functions perfectly, however when i .append() the logout link as a

```
<div class="nav_button">
```

it does not inherit any of the class CSS in the stylesheet for .nav_button, nor does it trigger the javascript hover event i have linked to the class

could someone explain to me the cause of this, as well as a way to resolve this problem?
Code is below, also any criticism of code is welcomed, still learning!

thanks.

### style.css

```
.nav_button {
display: inline;
border: 1px solid grey;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

### navmenu.php

```
<?php
// ---------------------------------------- Navigation bar ----------------------------------------
// Generate the navigation menu
$navbar = "";
$navbar = '<div id="nav_menu"><hr /><div id="nav_links">' . '<div class="nav_button"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>' . 
    '<div class="nav_button"><a href="signupAJAX.php">Sign Up</a></div>' .
    '<div class="nav_button"><a href="loginAJAX.php">Log In</a></div>';
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) // adds logout if logged in
{
    $navbar = $navbar . '<div class="nav_button"><a href="logout.php">Log Out <b><font color ="red">(' . $_SESSION['username'] . ')</font></b></a></div>';
}
$navbar = $navbar . '</div><hr /></div>';
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="navbutton.js"></script>

<?php
echo $navbar;
?>
```

### navbutton.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.nav_button').css('background-color', '#d6d6d6');
});

$(function() 
// ---------------------------------------- Nav button effects ----------------------------------------
{
$('.nav_button').mouseenter(function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color','#979191');  
});

$('.nav_button').mouseleave(function()
{
    $(this).css('background-color','#d6d6d6');
});
});
```

### login.php

```
<?php
// ---------------------------------------- User login page ----------------------------------------
require_once 'startsession.php';
$page_title = 'Log In';
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'navmenu.php';
?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="invisiblelogin.js"></script>

<?php
// Show login form if user not logged in
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) 
{
?>

<html> 
    <div id="contact_form">
        <form action="" name="contact">
            <fieldset><legend>Log In Info</legend>

                <label class="error" for="username" id="username_error">Invalid username/password combination.</label>
                <font color="red"><div id="Info"></div></font>

                <table>
                    <tr><td><label for="username" id="username_label">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" class="text-input" /></td>
                    <td><label class="error" for="username" id="username_error2">Enter your username.</label></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><label for="password" id="password_label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" class="text-input" /></td>
                    <td><label class="error" for="password" id="password_error">Enter your password.</label></td></tr>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Sign Up" />

            </fieldset>
        </form> 
    </div>
</html>

<?php
}
else 
{
    // Shown if user is logged in
    echo('<p class="login">You are logged in as <b><font color ="red">' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</b></font>.</p>');
}
require_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

### invisiblelogin.js

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('.error').hide(); 
$('#Info').hide();  
$('#loggedin').hide();
});

// ---------------------------------------- Verifies form fields have entries ----------------------------------------
$(function() 
{
$('.error').hide();
$(".button").click(function() 
{
    $('.error').hide();
    var username = $("input#username").val();
    var password = $("input#password").val();       

    if (username == "" || password == "") 
    { 
        if (username == "") 
        {
            $("label#username_error2").show();
            $("input#username").focus();
        }
        if (password == "") 
        {
            $("label#password_error").show();
            $("input#password").focus();
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Validation function
    if (username.length > 0 && password.length > 0) 
    {
        $.post("logincheck.php", {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val() },
        function(response) 
        {
            var valid = unescape(response);
            if (valid == 0) 
            {
                $("label#username_error").show();
            }
```

#### these lines are the append in invisiblelogin.js

```
            else 
            {
                $('#contact_form').html('<p class="login">You are logged in as <b><font color ="red">' + username + '</b></font>.</p>');
                $('#nav_links').append('<div class="nav_button"><a href="logout.php">Log Out <b><font color ="red">(' + username + ')</font></b></a></div>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }           
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: As per why your hover events aren't working, you're binding them when they don't exist yet, you'll need event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hover events aren't triggering because you're binding them before `.nav_button` exists on the page. Try this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.nav_button', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#979191');  
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#d6d6d6');
});
```

Per the CSS properties, don't set them in the DOM ready function, specify the background color inside the actual CSS file. Any appended elements with class `nav_button` will get the style.

Comment: thanks this worked for the hover event!  i had to separate mouseleave into its own .on() though because it didnt work as written